# Clicking a hyperlink if first 10 characters of href value = something

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm struggling with something. In Excel VBA I need to click on a hyperlink if the first few characters of the href value equals a given value. Consider the string below:

```
<li><a href="/Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/">Detail
```

So, in this example I basically want to evoke click only if the value of the first 15 characters of `href = "/Column/1234567"` AND if the `innertext = "Detail"`. There are other href's that start with `"/Column/1234567"` but which are not "Detail" and there are other innertexts that are Detail but with different starting href values. I only want to click if the 2 conditions are met. Can someone help with the VBA code?

Comment: Look into `instr/mid` etc.

Comment: Can you help me with the syntax? The varial myRef = “/Column/1234567”, so I tried :  
    If InStr(ele.href, myRef) = 1 Then
           Ele.click
    End If

But it does not seem to work.

Comment: `instr` is used by testing if it's `>0` not `=1`.

Comment: `instr(1,"/Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/">Detail", "Detail")` see [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85d3392c-3b1c-4232-bb18-77cd0cb8a55b)

Comment: I'm trying to test 2 conditions.  I'm trying to test if the first 15 characters of href are equal to "/Column/1234567" (or equals to the variable myRef) AND if the innertext of href = "Detail".  Both conditions must be met before clicking the URL of href.

Comment: If it's always first 15 then use `left`.

Comment: Yes, it will always be the first 15 characters.  The number sequence within the first 15 characters represents an ID.  So, I want to click the URL only if the ID matches and if the inner text is "Detail".  I'm familiar with the Left function, but not sure how to use it with href values.

Comment: The function operates the same regardless.

Comment: I understand that.  But how do I use if to grab the first 15 characters of the href value and use it in a conditional statement.  I know I can do something like: Left(href.value, 15), but what is the syntax for "href.value"? See the original HTML line I posted.

Comment: I don't know what `href.value` is. You just do `if(left(string,15)="foobar", true, false))`

Comment: Sorry, I think I’m not explaining myself correctly.  In my original example, the actual tag reads:
    <li><a href="/Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/">Detail</a>
So, what I want to do is compare the first 15 characters of the string ="/Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/" to a given string variable.  I also want to check if the innertext of the same tag is equal to “Detail”.

Comment: So, if my string variable is myVar= “/Column/1234567” then the result of my conditional statement for this tag would be TRUE and I would go ahead to click the hyperlink "/Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/".  Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Right and I have provided all the tools you need. I am not going to spoon feed you.

Comment: I'm not asking to be spoon fed. I'm familiar with the functions you mentioned. I just don't know the syntax of the href reference value.  How do I grab the string "Column/1234567/general-info/Weekly/Monday/" from the tag to make the comparison.? That is all I need.

Comment: This is what I have but it doesn’t work:
    
    For Each ele In ie.Document.all
      If InStr(ele.href, myRef) > 0 AND InStr(ele.innerText, "Detail") > 0 Then 
             MsgBox "Condition met"
        End If
Next ele

I think the logic is right, but I’m having trouble with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem.  After setting the value of the string variable myRef to the first 15 characters that I want to match, this is the code that worked:

```
    Set DetailLinks = ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
    For Each Hyperlink In DetailLinks
        If InStr(Hyperlink.href, myRef) And InStr(Hyperlink.innerText, "Detail") Then
            Hyperlink.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
```

@findwindow, thanks for the help provided.